# unable to perform dynamic search in react app using static data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am performing sort , filter and pagination on my react app which displays data from a json file which includes movies data. I am able to fetch data from input box  but unable to setState and also console log searchKey and movies.

Below is the code for App.js and Hello.js. App component has both sort and search functions.

> App.js

```
import data from './data.json';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: data.movies, sort_term: '', searchKey: '', filterList: '',
    };
    this.onSorting = this.onSorting.bind(this);
    this.onSearchMovie = this.onSearchMovie.bind(this);
  }
  onSorting = (e) => {
    let term = 'Title';
    let option = e.target.value;
    let sortedList = [...this.state.movies].sort((a, b) => {
      return (option == 'asc' ? (a[term] <= b[term] ? -1 : 1) :
        (a[term] >= b[term] ? -1 : 1))
    });
    this.setState({ sort_term: term });
    this.setState({ movies: sortedList });
  }
  onSearchMovie(e) {
    let key = e;
     console.log(key);
     this.setState({searchKey : key });
     console.log(searchKey);
     let list = movies.filter(m =>{
       return m.Title.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase());
     });
     this.setState({movies:list});
  }
  render() {
    const { movies } = this.state;

    if (!movies.length) {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <h2>loading...</h2>
        </div>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        <div>
          <Hello sort_term={this.state.sort_term}
            onSorting={this.onSorting}
            onSearch={this.onSearchMovie} />
          <br />
          <Table movies={this.state.movies} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

> Hello.js

```
class Hello extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { inputField: '', }
    this.onSubmitTitle = this.onSubmitTitle.bind(this);
    this.getTitle = this.getTitle.bind(this);
  }
  onSubmitTitle(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSearch(this.state.inputField);
    this.setState({ inputField: '' });
  }
  getTitle(e){
    this.setState({ inputField: e.target.value });
    // console.log('---');
  // console.log(this.state.inputField);
  }

  render() {
    const { sort_term, onSorting } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="header">
        Database
        <ul className="navLeft">
          <li>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitTitle}>
              <input type="search"  onChange={this.getTitle} value={this.state.inputField}
                className="search-bar"
                placeholder="Type for search..." />
            </form>
          </li>
          <li >
            <form >
              <select
                onChange={onSorting}
                className="searchBar">
                <option value="desc" >Sort Title(Z - A)</option>
                <option value="asc">Sort Title(A - Z)</option>
                 <option value="descDirector">Sort Director(Z - A)</option>
                <option value="ascDirector">Sort Director(A - Z)</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You got couple of issues:

- You got some undefined variables here:

  ```
          onSearchMovie(e) {
              let key = e;
              console.log(key);
              this.setState({ searchKey: key });
              console.log(searchKey);
              let list = movies.filter(m => {
                return m.Title.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase());
              });
              this.setState({ movies: list });
            }

   like `searchKey` and `movies`.
  ```
- `setState` is asynchronous, so doing this:

  ```
          this.setState({ sort_term: term });
          this.setState({ movies: sortedList });

          Is the same as doing this:  


          this.setState({
            sort_term: term,
            movies: sortedList
          });
  ```
- With that saying, this code block may not work as expected:

  ```
      onSearchMovie(e) {
        let key = e;
        console.log(key);
        this.setState({ searchKey: key });
        console.log(searchKey);
        let list = movies.filter(m => {
          return m.Title.toLowerCase().includes(searchKey.toLowerCase());
        });
        this.setState({ movies: list });
      }
  ```

  Because as mentioned above, `setState` is asynchronous. so `this.state.searchKey` may not be what you think when you access it the next line.
  Either use the `key` variable or use the `setState` callback which will trigger after `setState` has done.

  `this.setState({someKey: someValue}, () => {console.log(this.state.someKey)})`

  You can read more about it in the docs [Why is setState giving me the
  wrong value?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value).
- Another thing you may not know is that when you use `onSubmit` on a
  `form` you actually need to trigger the submit. Since you don't have 
  any submit button you can do it with the `enter` key. so while you
  are focused on the `input` press the `enter` key and the `form` will 
  get submitted.
- Another thing i would do, is to display and update a `filteredMovis`
  list instead of the `movies` list directly because once you filter
  out items then you can't get them back. so when you do filtering you
  do it on `movies` but updating the `filteredMovis` list without
  removing items from the original `movies` list.

Here is a working and running example:

```js
const data = {
  movies: [
    {
      id: 1,
      Title: "wonder woman"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      Title: "kill bill"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      Title: "world war z"
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      Title: "pixels"
    }
  ]
};

class Hello extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { inputField: "" };
    this.onSubmitTitle = this.onSubmitTitle.bind(this);
    this.getTitle = this.getTitle.bind(this);
  }
  onSubmitTitle(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.onSearch(this.state.inputField);
    this.setState({ inputField: "" });
  }
  getTitle(e) {
    this.setState({ inputField: e.target.value });
    // console.log('---');
    // console.log(this.state.inputField);
  }

  render() {
    const { onSorting } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className="header">
        Database
        <ul className="navLeft">
          <li>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitTitle}>
              <input
                type="text"
                onChange={this.getTitle}
                value={this.state.inputField}
                className="search-bar"
                placeholder="Type for search..."
              />
            </form>
          </li>
          <li>
            <form>
              <select onChange={onSorting} className="searchBar">
                <option value="desc">Sort Title(Z - A)</option>
                <option value="asc">Sort Title(A - Z)</option>
                <option value="descDirector">Sort Director(Z - A)</option>
                <option value="ascDirector">Sort Director(A - Z)</option>
              </select>
            </form>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      movies: data.movies,
      filteredMovis: data.movies,
      sort_term: "",
      searchKey: "",
      filterList: ""
    };
    this.onSorting = this.onSorting.bind(this);
    this.onSearchMovie = this.onSearchMovie.bind(this);
  }
  onSorting = e => {
    let term = "Title";
    let option = e.target.value;
    let sortedList = [...this.state.movies].sort((a, b) => {
      return option == "asc"
        ? a[term] <= b[term]
          ? -1
          : 1
        : a[term] >= b[term]
          ? -1
          : 1;
    });
    this.setState({
      sort_term: term,
      filteredMovis: sortedList
    });
  };
  onSearchMovie(key) {
    const { movies } = this.state;
    let list = movies.filter(m => {
      return m.Title.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase());
    });
    this.setState({ filteredMovis: list, searchKey: key });
  }
  render() {
    const { filteredMovis, movies } = this.state;

    if (!movies.length) {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <h2>loading...</h2>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <Hello
            sort_term={this.state.sort_term}
            onSorting={this.onSorting}
            onSearch={this.onSearchMovie}
          />
          <br />
          {filteredMovis.map(movie => <div key={movie.id}>{movie.Title}</div>)}
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: let list = movies.filter(m => {
      return m.Title.toLowerCase().includes(key.toLowerCase());
    });

Comment: I am getting movies is not defined but i have setState the movies

Comment: But you need to access it via the state object. `this.state.movies`

Comment: as of now I am able to search but it fails to display more then one data

Comment: for example if i have world war, wonder woman, world war z then it wont display searched result until i type uniquely the word

Comment: @AbhishekKonnur i provided a running example

Comment: ya i got it   const { movies } = this.state; this solved my error

Comment: On clearing everything from search box , all data must be displayed again. Its not displaying except searched data

Comment: I think that the knowledge and example i provided is enough for you to try solving this challenge. Remember, being better is not by letting other people solve your challenges :)